# Sum of Elements and margins is 100%, but line breaks

Tags: css

I would like to make a horizontal menu. I have a unordered list (`ul`) with three list elements (`li`). The list elements are forced to be in one line with `display: inline-block;`.

I like to get a margin of 5% on the left and the right side of the menu. Between the list elements, i have a margin of 1.5%.

```
margin-left (5%)
Element 1 (29%)
margin-right (1%)
margin-left (0.5%)
Element 2 (29%)
margin-right (0.5%)
margin-left (1%)
Element 3 (29%)
margin-right (5%)
```

If i add up all the percentages, I get 100%.

5 + 29 + 1 + 0.5 + 29 + 0.5 + 1 + 29 + 5 = 100

But unfortunately, the line breaks.

Following a example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8U5hM/2/

Thanks for hints!

Comment: Inline-block and whitespace is a pain in the butt. 

Chris Coyier offers an explanation and a bunch of solution options here:
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *whitespace* between your `display: inline-block;` elements. Just remove them or comment them.

[**Demo 1:**](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/8U5hM/3/)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="eins"></li><li id="zwei"></li><li id="drei"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[**Demo 2:**](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/8U5hM/4/)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="eins"></li><!--
     --><li id="zwei"></li><!--
     --><li id="drei"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the _withespace_. I haven't keep that in mind. Your Version with the HTML-comments brings a clear view into the structure.

Answer (score 0):

inline-block; reads the white spaces in your code. Edit your list to:

```
<li id="eins"></li><li id="zwei"></li><li id="drei"></li>
```

instead of

```
<li id="eins"></li>
<li id="zwei"></li>
<li id="drei"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrodie/8U5hM/11/) (you don't need to do it by ID but instead can use `:first-child`).

Relevant CSS:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    height: 40px;
    background: lime;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You may also put that your solution won't work on IE8 and less because `last-child` it a CSS3 selector -> [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)

Comment: What's about the performance when I use `first-child` and `last-child`? I think, IE8 and older are nowadays insignificant (but keep them in mind isn't wrong).

Comment: Here's a [CSS Wizardry](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) article on selector efficiency: in short, make them as specific as possible.

Comment: @Vucko As long as system critical functionality isn't broken by outdated browser incompatibility, it's not an issue, but +1 for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

change that:

```
nav ul li {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 ..
}
```

Comment: This is solving the problem, but then you have to deal with floats. I'm happy without having troubles with `float` and `clear`. ;-)